# prestashop language in module

Tags: module, prestashop

Im having a problem with an Invoice module in Prestashop 1.6
Depending on what language you choose the invoice is made in this language.

I want to make it to always use a defined language (in my case language id 2)

In the php file of the module I found a `language:getlanguage(false)` is this responsible for the language the module uses for creating the invoice ? and if yes how can i change it so it will pick only the language id 2?

thanks in advice

here is a snippet of the .php file

```
 /////////////////////
        $languagesArr=Language::getLanguages(false);
        $shopArrayList = Shop::getShops(false);
        foreach ($shopArrayList as $shopArray) {
            // update Setting
            $idsh = $shopArray['id_shop'];
            ///////////////
```

also there is this part containing something with language

```
///// insert invoice for language
            foreach ($languagesArr as $language) {
                $ba_lang =(int) $language['id_lang'];
```

some more info about the module: you can create templates for each language in my case i have one for german and one for russian.

```
 public function fillLanguageName($id_lang)
    {
        foreach ($this->languagesArr as $v) {
            if ($v["id_lang"]==$id_lang) {
                return $v["name"];
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should copy how the module generates the invoice

Comment: Do you mean the php file ?

Comment: Yes, but not all the php file, only the snippet

Comment: show us how looks function Language::getLanguages() - will be much easier to answer

Comment: where do I find it or can it look ?